# Random Space Insertion When Using Replace() Function in Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

We service multiple regions with regional copy and links in our emails. Because of this, we often rely on the use of data extensions with region IDs as a unique identifier and "tags" in the copy that we use to replace in-line formatting and links as needed. The reason for this is because we also have language translations and it makes it easier when pulling in region-specific links from another DE.

One anomaly that we're encountering in Content Builder, that wasn't in Classic, is the insertion of random spaces when we use the Replace() function to add in formatting or links in place of these "tags." This is consistent across all regions, but specifically seems to be when there is a replacement being made with a period following.

For this example, Variable @RegionID = 'USA'
DE Name: DE_Example

```
RegionID | Header            | Body
USA      | This [1]is[2] a header. | This is an [1]example[2].
```

Variable Setting:

```
VAR @RegionID, @Region_Copy_RS, @Region_Copy_ROW, @Region_Copy_Header, @Region_Copy_Body

SET @RegionID = [RegionID]
SET @Region_Copy_RS = LookupRows("DE_Example","RegionID",@RegionID)
SET @Region_Copy_ROW = Row(@Region_Copy_RS,1)
SET @Region_Copy_Header = Field(@Region_Copy_ROW,"Header")
SET @Region_Copy_Body = Field(@Region_Copy_ROW,"Body")
```

Now, if we wanted to bold anything that was framed with [1][2], we would replace each tag with `<span style='font-weight:bold;'>` and `</span>` respectively.

```
SET @Region_Copy_Header = Replace(@Region_Copy_Header,"[1]","<span style='font-weight:bold;'>")
SET @Region_Copy_Header = Replace(@Region_Copy_Header,"[2]","</span>")
SET @Region_Copy_Body = Replace(@Region_Copy_Body,"[1]","<span style='font-weight:bold;'>")
SET @Region_Copy_Body = Replace(@Region_Copy_Body,"[2]","</span>")
```

The expected outcome, as it has been in Classic, would be this:
This **is** a header.
This is an **example**.
But in Content Builder, this is what we're seeing:
This **is** a header.
This is an **example** .

As you can see, there is no addition space being added to the header, but there is a space being added between the word "example" and the period.

I'm not sure if anyone else has encountered this kind of anomaly or knows a solution around it. I have reviewed code and DE, and there isn't a space that's part of the data set nor is there a trailing space after the closing span tag in the Replace() function call. Again, it seems to be tied to Content Builder, so not sure if someone knows anything about how Content Builder's interface may differ from Classic to cause this.

Additional note: this is the case with ANY replacement. In this case we replaced with a span style, but if we replace with an A tag to link, it will also insert a random space.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some rendered code from the VAWP page source that illustrates the issue?

Comment: I would try using a `TRIM()` around your content calls to ensure there are no extra spaces coming in from somewhere. When I try this in content builder, I have it work exactly as expected with no added spaces... I duplicated your above code exactly.

Comment: @Gortonington, Do you mean when I actually do the %%=v(@Region_Copy_Body)=%% try %%=TRIM(@Region_Copy_Body)=%%? I tried that, but since the period is part of the content pulled in, and the space is inserted into the middle of it, it's not getting trimmed. Trim should only work for leading or trailing spaces, and this is in between characters.

Comment: Inside your example, the period is not inside the variable. If it is inside of it, then likely the issue is a 'GIGO' issue. To account for that, you could try doing a `%%=REPLACE(@Region_Copy_Body, " .", ".")=%%` to ensure any content inside with a space before a period is replaced to remove the space.

Comment: Hey @Gortonington! If you look at the "test DE," you can see that the periods are in the data table. I've also exported the DE's before and reviewed in various file editors (excel, VSC, notepad++, etc) to see if there were just odd "space characters," and nada. There is no space until a replace is made on the "tag" for formatting. This is only in CB and not Classic. I'll try method of replacing a " ." after the tag, though, and see if that renders anything different.

Comment: Following up. Added a Replace for " ." after all the other replaces, that didn't yield any different result. I added it inline as the print statement--also didn't yield any different results. The space is still displayed.

Comment: Can you provide a VAWP link or something like Adam asked and we can see if maybe there is an element of some kind causing the discrepancy